# How to concatenate strings to get the correct variable and function names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Considering this bit of code, I would like to be able to add values to the correct state using the same function to avoid code duplications. How can I concatenate strings to get the correct variable and function names?

```
const [questionsAdditionalProperties, setQuestionsAdditionalProperties] = useState([]);
const [usersAdditionalProperties, setUsersAdditionalProperties] = useState([]);


const handleAddAdditionalProperty = (type) => {
  //how to concatenate this valiable name to access the value in state?
  const key = ${type}AdditionalProperties.length;
  let newAdditionalProperty = [];
  newAdditionalProperty.push(
  // how to concatenate the function name to call the correct hook?
    getQuestionsAdditionalPropertiesRow(type, key)
  );
// how to concatenate the function name to call the correct hook and the variable name to use spread?
  setQuestionsAdditionalProperties([...questionsAdditionalProperties, ...newAdditionalProperty]);
};


<p className="right" onClick={e => handleAddAdditionalProperty("questions")}><Button variant="primary" >Add Question Additional Property</Button></p>

<p className="right" onClick={e => handleAddAdditionalProperty("users")}><Button variant="primary" >Add Users Additional Property</Button></p>
```

I don't want to use objects as this will lead me to refactor too much code in this application.

Comment: You can't access variable names from strings. You would need to make a single object state with each as a property

Comment: why not use an object instead?

Comment: Looks like you could just implement a reducer based on "type"

Comment: @pilchard can you show an example please?